# R (xlsx) - Write Multiple Excel Files From DF Based on Column Values

Tags: r, xlsx

I have a dataframe with many rows (>300,000) which I would like to write to multiple Excel files using xlsx package.

Sample data -

```
myData <- data.frame(Letter=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J"),
                 Fruit = c("Apples", "Pears", "Oranges", 
                           "Carrots", "Mangoes", "Potatoes",
                           "Bananas", "Plums","Grapes", 
                           "Broccoli"),
                 Country = c("Scotland", "Scotland", "Scotland",
                             "England", "England", "England",
                             "Wales", "Wales", "Wales",
                             "Ireland"))
```

So, from the sample data I would like to split my Excel workbooks by the 'Country' column.  There would be 4 Excel files with the country name as the filename and I would like them to look like below -

```
Letter  Fruit    Country
------------------------
A       Apples   Scotland
B       Pears    Scotland
C       Oranges  Scotland
```

Taking the 'Country' column out of the dataset would be a bonus.

I've figured out how to split these into multiple dataframes using a For loop, and then I could write a 'write.xlsx' line for each country.  But my list of countries is dynamic.  See below example -

```
for (i in unique(myData$Country)) {
  test <- paste0("excel", i)
  assign(test, myData[myData$Country == i,])
}
```

I've struggled to fit the write.xlsx function into that loop, but perhaps there's a better way.

Could anybody help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just split them into a list, then use an `lapply` for the write.xlsx. I'd suggest `lapply` over a `for-loop`.

```
myDatalist <- split(myData, myData$Country)
lapply(1:length(myDatalist), function(x) write.xlsx(myDatalist[[x]],
file = paste0(names(myDatalist[x]), ".xlsx"), row.names = FALSE))
```

All this does is apply a function to a list.

Comment: Thank you.  This works perfectly.  I had to switch to 'write.csv' due to memory issues, but the output is basically the same.  The use of functions like lapply is clearly an area where I need more practice.

Answer (score 1):

Using the For Loop method...

```
List <- list()

for (i in unique(myData$Country)) {
  test <- paste0("excel", i)
  testlist<-list(assign(test, myData[myData$Country == i,]))
  List[[test]]<-testlist
}
```

And as @Anonymous coward showed, simply apply the function to the list

```
lapply(1:length(List), function(x) write.xlsx(List[[x]],
       file = paste0(names(List[x]), ".xlsx"), row.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional option.  I went with @Anonymous Coward's answer as it worked perfectly with less code.